# In HNN Extensions, is the stable letter assumed to have order 2?

Tags: group-theory

I have been reading about HNN extensions, and trying to understand their construction with regard to normal/reduced form.

First, the construction of an HNN extension as I understand it is given, $A,B \leq G$ with $A$ and $B$ isomorphic via $\phi$, we take the free product of $G$ with the stable letter $t$ and mod out by the normal closure $tat^{-1}=\phi(a)$ for all $a\in A$. My question regards the normal form. Books suggest that all elements in the HNN extension can be written as $g_0t^{\epsilon_1}g_1t^{\epsilon_2}g_2\ldots t^{\epsilon_n}g_n$ where $\epsilon_i=\pm1$ and some other rules. This is called the normal form. What I'm wondering, how can every element be written like this? For example, how do we write out $t^2$? It seems the normal form is $etete$ but this is obviously not reduced, since $e$ appears. Are we just to accept that normal form and reduced form are incompatible? The use of the normal form is important in Britton's Lemma.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the normal form is indeed $etete$, but it is usually just written as $t^2$. The $g_i$ are allowed to be the identity, but there is a rule that you are not allowed to have $tet^{-1}$ or $t^{-1}et$ as a subword. What do you mean by "reduced form"?